# How to suppress/unsuppress mouse events on demand in Python?

Tags: python, pynput

This code will suppress the mouse events

`pynput.mouse.Listener(on_move=onMove, on_click=onClick, on_scroll=onScroll, suppress=True)`

but I want something like

```
def on_move(x,y):   
    if(something):     
        resend(x,y)   
    else:     
        //do something
```

I tried to resend using

`pynput.mouse.Controller().move(x,y)` and `pyautogui.moveRel(x,y)`
but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "resend"? Do you want to allow the user to move the mouse again?

Comment: @5rod e.g. only suppress mouse events if Shift key is pressed

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I would _not_ recommend trying this, except for a few exceptions to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't understand why you would want to do this, but here's what I came up with:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener

def on_suppress_move(x, y):
    #do stuff
    if not condition:
        return False

def on_move(x, y):
    #do stuff
    if condition:
        return False

while True:
    if(condition):
        with Listener(on_move=on_suppress_move, suppress=True) as listener:
            listener.join()
    
    else:
        with Listener(on_move=on_move) as listener:
            listener.join()
```

This should work. We run through a while loop, constantly checking if the condition is True/False depending on the function. We return False from the function (and therefore stop the listener) when the condition is not met. After the `else` statement is finished, the loop starts over again (and therefore we repeat). In this fashion, this works forever.

This would be really hard to do if the condition was something like if the key shift is pressed.